# \listoftodos in Todo list missing hyperlinks and colors in my document

Tags: table-of-contents, todonotes, textmate

I'm trying to add a `\listoftodos` using the `todonotes` package to a template file I have. I've added two todos with `\todo[inline]{Write abstract \ldots}` and `\todo{Fill in these details \ldots}`. I'm using TextMate to render my document on Mac Osx.

My list of todos in my document looks like this:
[image: TODO List]

My table of contents (in Estonian) looks like this (I think it might be interfering with the styling):
[image]

And finally, the intended behaviour and styling from `todonotes` [documentation](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) looks like this with hyperlinks and colors:
[image]

Do you have any ideas how to debug the styling issues with rendering todos?

Comment: Please provide an MWE which illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please add in the future always an MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. It makes everything for all easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option `[colorinlistoftodos]` to your documentclass, see [1.2 Package options,p.4:colorinlistoftodos](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf).

colorinlistoftodos:

> Adds a small colored square in front of all items in the Todo list.

For hyperlinks you nedd `\usepackage{hyperref}` or without box `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[colorinlistoftodos]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

\section{Contents}
\todo[color=green!40]{And a green note}
test text \todo{test}
\todo{Make a cake \ldots}
\todo[linecolor=green!70!white, backgroundcolor=blue!20!white,
bordercolor=red]{Anything but default colors}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, I see the colors now!
But I'm still missing the hyperlinks to the todos... Do you have the hyperlinks in your doc?

Comment: Do you mean `\usepackage{hyperref}` or `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`?

Comment: @craastad Be careful, if your document is typeset in `draft` mode (i. e. you have given the option `\documentclass[draft,...]{scrartcl}`, hyperlinks won't be activated.  just replace `draft` with `final`  and everything should be fine.