# A moveable/copyable icon to give the user a link

Tags: hyperref, links, adobe, pdfcomment

The hyperref package allows to put a link within the stream of the text.
The PDFcomment allow to create "floating" stickynotes that can be copied and moved around in a page.
Is it possible to have a "floating" icon that link to somewhere : through a package ? or at least authorized by the pdf document structure ? if possible without the use of javascript to minimize the restriction on readers on mobile platforms ?

Comment: I removed the `floats` tag as you're not talking about a float in the LaTeX sense.

Comment: Do you know the pack­age `todonotes`, which lets you mark things.For example [\listoftodos in Todo list missing hyperlinks and colors in my document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357941/124842).

Comment: @ Bobyandbob : I encountered the package a while ago. In fact the notes are in the stream : the user can't move them on the pdf document when he can with the sticky notes. The hyperref use with the hidelinks option give a nice look but it is also in the stream.